# Handle middleware using chai-http Node Js Express

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am facing issue I am testing an api using chai-http but it struck in middlewear means it does not call next() function. Not sure how to handle this, little guide may be helps me alot. Here is my code may be it helps you understand better.

**Middleware**

```
function middleware(req, res, next) => {
  // doing some stuff
  console.log("step 1") // prints
  next()
}
```

**API**

```
router.get('/orders', middleware, (req, res) => {
  // some stuff
 console.log("step 2") // not prints
 res.send(result)
})
```

**Test Case**

```
  let order = new Order(mockOrder);
  order.save((err, order) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/orders')
    .end((err, res) => {
    // some stuff
   })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This update might be useful for you.It is from github.

Another large breaking change is that the chai.request(server) object will automatically close the server connection after the first request. This means if you have code like this:

you'll need to change it to:

```
const request = chai.request(app).keepOpen()
```